# What is the right place to require a ruby module in rails 3 & ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to use the CSV module built into Ruby 1.9.2, and, in order to do this, I need to do `require 'csv'`.

In Rails 3, where is the proper place to put this `require`? I have seen examples where it's at the top of the file it's used in.

I have also see an example where it's put in `config/initializers/csv_init.rb`.

Is there a rule of thumb here? If I need it in multiple files, put it in an initializer, if only one put it in the file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in 'config/application.rb'. (See "[Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)").

In general, do this stuff in a central place and document it. The person maintaining your application will appreciate it when some future Ruby or Rails version breaks all kinds of backward compatibility.